# How to swap first and last nibbles in given integer [32 bits]

Tags: c, integer, bit-manipulation, bit, byte-shifting

Suppose :

```
No = 77
77 in binary [32 bits] : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 1101
```

I have to swap first and last nibble:

```
i.e :                    1101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000
```

I was doing something like this:

```
no << 32 | no >> 32
```

Then in a loop anding it with 1 and printing. But it does not work out.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int decimalNumber;
    printf("Enter your decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &decimalNumber);
    int i, j;
    
    /* Binary conversion */
    for(i=31;i>=0;i--)
    {

        printf("%d", (decimalNumber >> i) & 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("After nibble swapping: \n");
    /* Nibble swapping */
    decimalNumber = (decimalNumber>>28) | (decimalNumber<<28);
    for(i=31;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d",((decimalNumber>>i)&1 ? 1 : 0));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and include some code (as text).

Comment: Shifting by 32 is too far.

Comment: _"Then in a loop anding it with 1 and printing. But it does not work out."_: it would be more helpful if you showed your code instead of describing it. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: This is the output produced by the code
Output:

Enter your decimal number: 77
00000000000000000000000001001101
After nibble swapping: 
11010000000000000000000000000000

But the expected output after nibble swapping is :  11010000000000000000000001000000

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this as i am new to this concept and stuck on the issue

Comment: Don't use `int`, it's size is platform specific, and your problem only really make sense for unsigned values.

Comment: `decimalNumber = (decimalNumber>>28) | (decimalNumber<<28);` swap the lower an upper bits but you lose the middle 24 bits.

Comment: `decimalNumber & 0x0ffffff0` is the middle bits, or you can use the shift pattern in my answer below `decimalNumber << 4 >> 4 >> 4 << 4`.  Also instead of duplicating the code to print a binary number write a function `void print_bits(unsigned int v) {                           
          for(int i=31;i>=0; i--)
                printf("%d", (v >> i) & 1);            
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> swap first and last nibbles in given integer (32 bits)

OP's `decimalNumber = (decimalNumber>>28) | (decimalNumber<<28);` fails as the `|` *or's* the data, not replace it.  Also shifting by 28 shifts the middle bits, which need to remain in place.

---

- Use *unsigned* types to not shift into or out of the sign bit.
- For a fixed sized tasks, consider using fixed sized types from `#include <stdint.h>`.
- Print data with %X to better see what is happening.

```
    uint32_t uvalue = decimalNumber;
    printf("Before %lu\n", (unsigned long) uvalue);   // In decimal
    printf("Before 0x%lX\n", (unsigned long) uvalue); // In hexadecimal

    // Get first (most significant) and last (least significant) nibble.
    uint32_t first_nibble = uvalue >> (32-4);
    uint32_t last_nibble = uvalue & 0xF;

    // zero out the first and last nibble.
    uvalue &= 0x0FFFFFF0; 
    // Now "or" in the replacement nibbles.
    uvalue |= first_nibble;
    uvalue |= last_nibble << (32-4);

    printf("After 0x%lX\n", (unsigned long) uvalue);
    printf("After %lu\n", (unsigned long) uvalue);
```

For those who like one-liners

```
printf("After %lu\n", (unsigned long) (
    (((uint32_t) decimalNumber) & 0xF) << 28) |
    ((uint32_t) decimalNumber) & 0x0FFFFFF0) |
    ((uint32_t) decimalNumber) >> 28) |
    ));
```

---

Some would consider the first nibble as the least significant nibble.  Whatever is first or last makes little difference here as they are swapped.

Comment: Yeah, I used masks initially, but thought it was sub-optimal to assume a fixed size of the input.  Is there a way to cast any signed int type the corresponding unsigned type?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, via `_Generic`.

Answer (score 2):

Given an unsigned integer `d` and `b` number of bits where `b <= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(d) / 2` you obtain the result by bitwise `OR` of these components:

1. Left shift the lower `b` bits to the top (`sizeof (d) - (b)` is `28` bits in this case).  When you left shift the lower bits become 0. With example data the value is `0x8000000`.
2. The left followed by right shift clears the top `b` bits, and the right followed by left shift clears the lower `b` bits.  With the example data the value is `0x02345670`.  This equivalent bitwise `AND` of the mask `0x0ffffff0` for a 32-bit number.  The shift works for any unsigned integer type irregardless of size.
3. Right shift the top `b` bits to the bottom.  When you right shift the upper `b` bits become zero.  With the example data the value is `0x00000001`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SWAP_BITS(d, b) \
    /* 1 */ (d) << CHAR_BIT * sizeof (d) - (b) |\
    /* 2 */ (d) << (b) >> (b) >> (b) << (b) |\
    /* 3 */ (d) >> CHAR_BIT * sizeof (d) - (b)

int main() {
    uint32_t d = 0x12345678;
    printf("%x\n%x\n", d, SWAP_BITS(d, 4));
}
```

and the outcome is:

```
82345671
```

Comment: There are 3 lines of code in the macro and a sentence that describes each line.  What is unclear?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, I inadvertently broke the code with the line comments when I did not hear back from op.  Fixed those.

Comment: Note that `SWAP_BITS(d, b)` works well here if `b` in the range [1...16].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Why the 16 bit limit?  So I can revise answer.

Comment: Ask yourself what should `0x12345678` result with `b == 20`?  As is, code would `|` middle 8 bits.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica so `b < CHAR_BIT * sizeof(d)/ 2`  but if  you passed in an uin64_t it would be fine, right?  (and yeah, I understand op is asking about 32 bit just making sure that I am missing anything else).

Comment: More like `b <= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(d)/ 2` - but yes, you have the right idea.